# Как достичь последнего показателя за минимальное количество прыжков?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Учитывая массив неотрицательных целых чисел nums, вы изначально занимаетесь первым индексом массива.

Каждый элемент в массиве представляет вашу максимальную длину прыжка в этой позиции.

Ваша цель - достичь последнего показателя за минимальное количество прыжков.

```
Input: nums = [2,3,1,1,4]
Output: 2
```

Explanation: The minimum number of jumps to reach the last index is 2. Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: За квадратичное время можно решить. Быстрее получится?

Comment: @MBo получится за nlogn точно, про линию нужно думать. Два способа: 1) очевидное дп + дерево отрезков, обновляющее минимум на отрезке (напряжно написать, зато простая идея); 2) делаем преобразование каждого элемента в отрезок [i; i + a[i]] и решаем задачу о покрытии отрезка [0; M] с помощью минимального количества отрезков.

Comment: Скорее всего можно линейно через очередь минимумов, но нет времени сейчас развивать идею

Comment: @MBo, вроде получилось за линейное :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Ага, я заметил, у всех интересно, всех уплюсовал ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если за некое число прыжков мы можем допрыгнуть до позиции x, то за это же (или меньшее) число мы можем допрыгнуть до любой более ранней позиции. Для каждого элемента проверяем, позволяет ли он нам расширить нашу правую границу и если да, то делаем это. Граница является линией следующего прыжка - каждый раз доходя до неё мы увеличиваем число прыжков на 1 и сдвигаем границу в следующую возможную точку. Это линейный алгоритм.

```js
var a = [2,3,1,1,4]

var lim = 0, nextLim = 0, x = 0

for (var res=0; lim<a.length-1; lim=nextLim, ++res) {
  for (; x<=lim; ++x) {
    nextLim = Math.max(nextLim, x+a[x])
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Да, и вправду круто. Забавно, что самое эффективное решение пишется проще, чем все остальные).

Comment: Я протестировал вашу идею на чистой задаче о минимальном покрытии и она зашла, так что еще и спасибо вам за новый способ решения - возможно, мне когда-нибудь это пригодится

Answer (score 3):

Задача правда забавная. Как мы и писали в комментариях, есть много решений с разной эффективностью, я пройдусь по тем, которые пришли мне в голову еще тогда, начиная с наименее эффективных и заканчивая линейным алгоритмов, который является наиболее оптимальным для данной задачи.

Для начала стоит отметить BFS. Данную задачу очень просто свести к поиску кратчайшего пути в ориентированном графе, заданном неявно. Пусть вершинами будут все элементы массива, и пусть из вершины v исходят ребра во все вершины с номерами в отрезке [v - a[v]; v + a[v]]. Асимптотика BFS - O(V + E), то есть сумма ребер и вершин, которая в худшем случае равна O(n^2).

Далее все мои решения используют очевидную идею о том, что в оптимальном маршруте нет переходов налево. Докажем этот факт.

Назовем любую последовательность T[] вершин от 0 до N - 1 траекторией, если T[0] = 0 и для любого 1 <= i < T.length верно 0 < |T[i] - T[i - 1]| <= A[i - 1]. Назовем решением траекторию, кончающуюся в вершине N - 1. Назовем оптимальным решением любое решение, которое имеет длину M такую, что не существует никакого решения длины меньшей M.

Тогда докажем, что если существует хотя бы одно решение, то существует оптимальное решение, в котором все вершины расположены в строго возрастающем порядке (нет шагов налево). Доказывать будет от противного: допустим, все оптимальные решения включают в себя шаги налево, тогда выберем любое из них и назовем его O[]. Пусть v - минимальный такой индекс, что O[v] < O[v - 1] (то есть, что на v-том шаге мы пошли налево). Тогда найдем максимальный индекс u, меньший v, такой, что O[u] < O[v]. Следовательно, O[u + 1] >= O[v], а значит, A[O[u]] >= O[u + 1] - O[u] >= O[v] - O[u], а значит уже на u-том шаге можно было попасть в вершину O[v], что означает, что мы даже улучшили оптимальное решение, что невозможно по его определению, а значит, изначальная посылка неверна и существует оптимальное решение, в котором мы только идем направо.

С нудной частью покончено (если вы потребуете большей строгости, то я ее, конечно, распишу, но от такой нудятины вы точно бросите читать этот ответ). Теперь быстро напишу идеи решений.

Еще одно квадратичное решение - динамическое программирование. Пусть dp[i] - минимальная длина пути до i-того элемента, тогда очевидно dp[0] = 0, dp[i] = min(dp[j]) для всех j таких, что j < i и A[j] >= i - j. Тогда мы можем написать следующий псевдокод:

```
dp[0..N-1] = [0] + [N] * (N - 1)
for i in 0..N-1:
    for j in (i + 1) .. min(i + A[i], N - 1):
        dp[j] = min(dp[j], dp[i] + 1)
ans = dp[N - 1]
```

Теперь поговорим о линейно-логарифмических решениях (ответ мой, термины будут тоже мои).

Первое пришедшее мне в голову решение вообще - это улучшение предыдущего с помощью дерева отрезков. Если мы сможем заставить наше дерево обновлять минимумы на отрезке и получать значения этих минимумов на точке, то код выглядит как-то так:

```
dp[0..N-1] = [0] + [N] * (N - 1)
tree = SegmentTree(dp)
for i in 0..N-1:
    tree.update(i + 1, min(i + A[i], N - 1), tree.get(i))
ans = tree.get(N - 1)
```

Я могу сказать, что такое дерево отрезков написать действительно можно, и это на самом деле даже не так сложно, как звучит, но так как этот ответ все равно никому не нужен, делать я этого, конечно же, не буду.

Теперь моя идея с отрезками. Заметим, что из точки i мы можем прийти в любую точку на отрезке [i; i + A[i]]. Очевидно, что для любой точки на этом отрезке мы тоже можем пройти дальше - на любую точку из некоторого отрезка [j; j + A[j]]. А если j находится вне отрезка, образованного i-тым элементом, то пройти в такую точку j мы не можем. Тогда получается, что если мы хотим прийти в некоторую точку M, то нам необходимо покрыть весь отрезок [0; M] нашими новообразованными отрезочками. Тогда такая задача превращается в такую задачу: найти наименьшее множество отрезков, которое полностью покрывает отрезок [0; M]. Только в нашем случае M всегда равен N - 1.

Такая задача решается достаточно просто: рассмотрим множество всех отрезков, правые концы которых не левее, чем M. Выберем из них такой отрезок, левый конец которого минимален. Тогда мы можем перейти к задаче меньшей размерности - присвоить M значение этого левого конца. Если теперь M <= 0, то алгоритм нужно завершить и утверждается (мной), что так будет найдено оптимальное решение.

Чтобы это делать быстро мы отсортируем все отрезки по убыванию (невозрастанию) правого конца и будем идти по ним, пока правый конец не левее M. При этом для каждого пройденного отрезка мы обновляем значение минимального левого конца и когда все такие отрезки пройдены, присваиваем это значение минимума текущему M. Псевдокод:

```
# питоноподобный синтаксис
B = [[i, i + A[i]] for i in range(N)]
B.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
ans = 0
m = n - 1
i = 0
while m > 0:
    ans += 1
    l_min = N
    while i > 0 and B[i][1] >= m:
        l_min = min(l_min, B[i][0])
        i -= 1
    if l_min >= m:
        print('No solution')
        exit()
    m = l_min
```

К сожалению, линейный алгоритм в конце концов у меня составить не получилось. Несмотря на то, что отрезки отсортированы по левому концу изначально, лично мне это никак не помогло найти какой-то жадный или структурный алгоритм, который позволяет решать задачу за O(n).

Comment: Я вами восхищен. Можно Ваш автограф?

Comment: Посмотри мой - он линейный, но я не совсем уверен почему-то в нём...

Answer (score 3):

Пусть мы знаем диапазон индексов достижимых из стартовой позиции за `k` прыжков и не достижимых за меньшее количество прыжков. Пробежим по этому диапазону отыскивая `max(i + nums[i])`. Это даст правую границу аналогичного диапазона для `k + 1` прыжка. Левая граница для `k + 1` уже известна, она совпадает с правой для `k`. Это даёт линейный алгоритм.

Числа в массиве неотрицательные, что создаёт возможность построить массив не имеющий решения.

```
nums = [2, 3, 1, 1, 4]

n = len(nums) - 1
k = 0
begin = 0
end = 1

while end <= n:
    next_end = max(i + nums[i] for i in range(begin, end)) + 1
    assert next_end > end
    begin = end
    end = next_end
    k += 1

print(k)
```